# Hibernate : How to write a criteria with combination of conjunction and disjunction?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a list of filter objects : FilterVO

public class FilterVO {

```
public paramName;
public String criteria;
public String value;
public String relation;
```

}

The size of the filter object and the content is selected by the end user through UI:

I have to query the database based on this filter objects:

For Ex:

```
 filterVO1 = ["param1",">","value1",AND]
 filterVO2 = ["param2","<","value2",OR]
 filterVO3 = ["param3","like","%value3",AND]
 filterVO4 = ["param4","=","value5",OR]
 filterVO5 = ["param5",">","value6"]
```

Can you suggest how to dynamically build the Criteria object for above filter with combination of "AND", "OR".

I have written the following code :

```
   if (relation.equalsIgnoreCase("OR")) 
    {
        disJunction.add(getRestriction(criteria, paramName, value));
            maincriteria.add(disJunction);
} else  if (relation.equalsIgnoreCase("AND")) 
    {
    conJunction.add(getRestriction(criteria, paramName, value));
            maincriteria.add(conJunction);
}
```

This code is not working properly for AND , OR combination. It is always taking AND condition. Please give an example code for for AND,OR combination.